# How to set the width of Vertical Bar Charts in ngx-Chart?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am using the Vertical Bar Chart in my project. I don't know how to adjust the width of the bar of the chart.
If I have multiple bars on charts, it looks good but if I have a single bar on the charts it takes the whole space on the chart and looks like a piece of a block on the chart. If there is a possible way to fix this issue please help me.